# ext js combo behavior

Tags: extjs

For extjs combo, here is the behavior I am trying to udnerstand. When we start typing in characters in the combo, by default, it filters the dropdown list based on the characters typed in. However, if I type some characters and click on the trigger button, the list is the master list(not filtered)?

What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the list rendering takes place in the view of the combo, and the actual list is stored in the model. So if you pull the trigger button, the real list is taken from the model, not from the rendered/filtered list in the view.

Comment: So on click of trigger button, if I wish to have a filtered list (simialr to if I input text in the combo), do I manipulate the 'triggerOption' variable?

Comment: How can I dynamically set the triggerOption? combo.setTriggerOption('query')?

Answer (score 0):

By clicking the trigger button, you change input modality: Once you were using keyboard input and now you've switched to the mouse. I think the current behaviour makes sense: you either continue using the keyboard (i.e. arrow through the filtered values) or switch to the mouse completely (and you're back to square one).